# How to use sendkeys on child window in salesforce using selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, salesforce

I want to use `sendkeys` on a **search textbox** of child window displayed in these [screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXRT7.jpg) .

I'm able to find URl, and title name of child window, **but** whenever I want to `click`, `sendkeys` on child window, the code is halted in between with the error: `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element`

Please suggest how to solve above query.

Comment: hi can u post the source code of the child window

Comment: Yes .. I m posting screenshots of child's inspect element code

Comment: its better if you post the source code instead of screenshot.

Comment: which browser u are using and is this opened in a new window....also check the window html is there any frame and let me know

Comment: Since your searchbox is in a different window, you first need to switch to that window before you can interact with elements on it.

Comment: hey @noor , I'm using chrome browser

Comment: Yes @Mobrockers, I first switched to child window, still not able to intrect with elements. but i m able to get child page title, URL ... could u plz tell me wat shud do

Comment: Does the child page perhaps have a frame (iframe or just frame) you need to switch to first?

Comment: yes @Mobrockers  .. there were frames. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

hope there is no frame and if this opens in a new window, try the below:

```
Thread.sleep(2000);
// Store the current window handle
String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();

// Perform the click operation that opens new window

// Switch to new window opened
for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
}

// Perform the actions on new window
driver.findElement(By.xpath("ur xpath of that search box")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("ur xpath of that search box")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("ur xpath of that search box")).sendKeys("ur text");


// Close the new window, if that window no more required
driver.close();

// Switch back to original browser (first window)
driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);
```